# Return List of Database Users and Server Logins

Tags: sql-server

How can I return a complete listing of all server logins and all database users across my enterprise? Need to include the remote server name, database name, AD account and SQL users.

Comment: Yes that would be useful information. Sorry! Our enterprise consists of SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 & 2014.

Comment: Is this something you want to collect for historical purposes, documentation, just a one-time thing? What have you tried so far or looked at doing?

Comment: When you say "database" are you referring to the accounts default database or all databases they have access to?

Comment: This sounds like a job for PowerShell and SMO.

Comment: It is intended to be used as a reoccuring documenting process.

Comment: I would like to have a list of each SQL\AD user accounts and what databases they have access to and server name. How to query hundreds of database servers across the the enterprise. Ideally the query/package run from one server would query this information and return it to the server where the query/package is executed and placed in a table.

Answer (score 1):

For such purpose i use this login audit script which gives me detailed information of logins and users attached to them along with database and server level permissions. Overall can be helpful to you :

```
if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.all_objects where name like '%#Login_Audit%') 
drop table #Login_Audit 
create table #Login_Audit 
(A nvarchar (500),B nvarchar (500)default (''),C nvarchar (200)default (''), D nvarchar (200)default ('')) 
go 

insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[Security Report] = '-----SQL SERVER SECURITY AUDIT Report-----','-----','-----','-----' 
go   
insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[Login count] = 'Total Count of Login','Windows User','SQL server User','Windows Group' 
go    

insert into #Login_Audit  
select a,b,c,d from 
(select count(name)a from sys.syslogins where name not like '%#%') a, -- total count 
(select count (name)b from sys.syslogins where name not like '%#%'and isntuser=1) b, -      -for login is windows user  
(select count (name)c from sys.syslogins where name not like '%#%'and isntname=0) c, -- for login is sql server login  
(select count (name)d from sys.syslogins where name not like '%#%'and isntgroup=1 )d; 
go 

insert into #Login_Audit (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[sysadmin_server role] = '-- SYSADMIN SERVER ROLE ASSIGN TO---',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
go 
insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[Sys Admin role] = 'Login name',' Type ',' Login Status ','' 
go 
insert into #Login_Audit (A,B,C) 
SELECT a.name as Logins, a.type_desc, case a.is_disabled  
when 1 then 'Disable' 
when 0 then 'Enable' 
End 
FROM sys.server_principals a  
INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members b ON a.principal_id = b.member_principal_id 
WHERE b.role_principal_id = 3 
ORDER BY a.name 
go 

insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[Fixed_server role] = '-- FIXED SERVER ROLE DETAILS --',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
 go 
insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[Fixed_server role] = 'ROLE name',' Members ',' Type ','' 
 go 

 insert into #Login_Audit (A,B,C) 
  SELECT c.name as Fixed_roleName, a.name as logins ,a.type_desc  
 FROM sys.server_principals a  
 INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members b ON a.principal_id = b.member_principal_id 
 INNER JOIN sys.server_principals c ON c.principal_id = b.role_principal_id 
--WHERE a.principal_id > 250 
 ORDER BY c.name  
 go 

 insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
 SELECT 
[Fixed_database_Roles] = '-- FIXED DATABASE ROLES DETAILS --',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
go 
insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 
[Fixed_database_Role] = 'Database Name','Role Name','Member','Type' 
go 
insert into #Login_Audit exec master.dbo.sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?] 
SELECT db_name()as DBNAME, c.name as DB_ROLE ,a.name as Role_Member, a.type_desc 
FROM sys.database_principals a  
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members b ON a.principal_id = b.member_principal_id 
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals c ON c.principal_id = b.role_principal_id 
WHERE a.name <> ''dbo''and c.is_fixed_role=1 ' 
go 
------------ used is_fixed = 0 for non fixed database roles(need to run on each database) 
 insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
 SELECT 
 [NON_Fixed_database_Roles] = '-- NON FIXED DATABASE ROLES DETAILS --',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
 go 
 insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
 SELECT 
 [Non Fixed_database role] = 'Database Name','Role Name','Member ','Type' 
  go 
  insert into #Login_Audit exec master.dbo.sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?] 
  SELECT db_name()as DBNAME, c.name as DB_ROLE ,a.name as Role_Member, a.type_desc 
  FROM sys.database_principals a  
  INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members b ON a.principal_id = b.member_principal_id 
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals c ON c.principal_id = b.role_principal_id 
  WHERE a.name <> ''dbo''and c.is_fixed_role=0 ' 
  go 

   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
   SELECT 
    [Server_Level_Permission] = '-- SERVER LEVEL PERMISSION DETAILS --',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
   go 
   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
   SELECT 
   [Server permission] = 'Logins','Permission Type',' Permission_desc ','Status' 
   go 
   insert into #Login_Audit  
   SELECT b.name,a.type,a.permission_name,a.state_desc 
   FROM sys.server_permissions a  
   INNER JOIN sys.server_principals b ON a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id 
 --INNER JOIN sys.server_principals b ON b.principal_id = b.role_principal_id 
   WHERE b.name not like '%#%' 
   ORDER BY b.name 
   go 

   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
  SELECT 
  [DATABASE_Level_Permission] = '-- DATABASE LEVEL PERMISSION DETAILS ----',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
  go 

  insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
  SELECT 
  [DB permission] = 'Database Name','Login Name',' Permission ','Status' 
  go 

  insert into #Login_Audit 
  exec master.dbo.sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?] 
  SELECT db_name () as DBNAME,b.name as users,a.permission_name,a.state_desc 
  FROM sys.database_permissions a  
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals b ON a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id 
  where a.class =0 and b.name <> ''dbo'' and b.name <> ''guest''and   b.name not like   ''%#%''' 
  go 

   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
  SELECT 
  [Password_ Policy_Details] = '--- PASSWORD POLICY DETAILS ----',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
   go 

   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
   SELECT 
   [Policy] = 'Users','type',' Policy status','Password policy status' 
   go 

   insert into #Login_Audit 
   SELECT a.name AS SQL_Server_Login,a.type_desc,  
   CASE b.is_policy_checked  
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Password Policy Applied' 
   ELSE 
   'Password Policy Not Applied' 
   END AS Password_Policy_Status, 
   CASE b.is_expiration_checked  
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Password Expiration Check Applied' 
  ELSE 
 'Password Expiration Check Not Applied' 
 END AS Password_Expiration_Check_Status  
 FROM sys.server_principals a INNER JOIN sys.sql_logins b 
 ON a.principal_id = b.principal_id  
 where a.name not like '%#%' 
 order by a.name 
  go 


  insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
  SELECT 
  [Orphan_Login_Details] = '--- ORPHAN LOGINS ----',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
  go 

  insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
  SELECT 
   [orphan logine] = 'Logins Name','ID','','' 
   go 

   insert into #Login_Audit (A,B) exec sp_validatelogins 
   go 

   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
   SELECT 
   [Orphan_USERS_Details] = '--- ORPHAN USERS----',' ----- ',' ----- ',' ----- ' 
   go 
   insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
    SELECT 
    [orphan users] = 'User Name','','  ','' 
    go 
    insert into #Login_Audit (A)  
    select u.name from master..syslogins l right join  
    sysusers u on l.sid = u.sid  
    where l.sid is null and issqlrole <> 1 and isapprole <> 1    
    and (u.name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' and u.name <> 'guest'   
    and u.name <> 'system_function_schema'and u.name <> 'sys') 

    insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
    SELECT 
    [Database_Owner_details] = '--- DATABASE OWENER DETAILS----',' ----- ',' ----- ','   ----- ' 
    go   
    insert into #Login_Audit  (A,B,C,D) 
    SELECT 
    [DB owner] = 'Database Name','Owener name','  ','' 
    go 
    insert into #Login_Audit (A,B)    
    select name, SUSER_sNAME (owner_sid) from sys.databases order by name asc  
     go 

    select * from #Login_Audit
```

Comment: there are better ways to avoid `master.dbo.sp_MSforeachdb` - undocumented and unreliable. A set based approach or Aaron's version of msforeachdb would be much better choice IMHO + your table `#Login_Audit` should have sensible column names as well .. not `A,B,C,D` !

Comment: There is a typo 'Owener Name'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that I use for such things.  This one only works on 2012 and up, but it should be easy to remove the references to columns that don't exist in the 2005-2008 system tables.

```
/****************
Name: User Analysis Mk2
Author: Jonathan Fite
Date: 1/23/2015

Purpose: To display the individually set permissions for every user in the current database. 

USAGE: Execute script to see details of what type of access has been granted where.

NOTES:
    - Recursive, so that a user who is a member of a role, which is a member of a role is displayed, use
        the "RoleGrantedThrough" column to see this recursiong.
    - But selecting to a specific value in the "UserName" column, will show you everything that user has. 
    - Displays relevant objects that has been granted to.  

FIX QUERIES:
    There are a few fix queries at the bottom of this file (commented out) that are designed to help with 
    targeting and resolving specific issues.  Orphaned Users, Schema Ownership, etc.  

    Usage for these is recommended to target a specific issue such as orphaned users, fix that issue to your
    satisfaction and then run this script again before targeting a second "issue".  

    Targeted Issue Fix:
        - Orphaned Users - Identify users who don't have a link to a server level account, then script out
            their removal.  Handles whether they own schemas or not.

        - Fix Schemas owned by Orphaned Users - Identify schemas that are owned by orphaned users (without fixing
            the orphaned user issue).  Schemas with no objects are dropped.  Schemas with objects have their
            ownership changed to dbo.  

        - Fix GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION - Identify permissions where a user is able to further grant permissions to others.
            Their permission will be changed to just "GRANT".

        - Fix REFERENCE - Identify REFERENCE permissions and remove the permission completely.  



OUTPUT:

    #UserPermissions
    - ServerName - the name of the server.
    - DatabaseName - the name of the database (For server level, the database is null).
    - UserName - the name of the user.
    - SID - the SID of the user in question (for tracking up to sys.server_principals if desired).
    - RoleName - the name of the role.
    - Usertype - the type of user (U,G,R, etc.)
    - UserTypeDescription - the description of the user type.
    - DefaultSchema - the users default schema.
    - create_date - the date the user was created.
    - GrantedThroughName - the name of the role that the access was granted through.
    - SchemaName - the schema of the object in question.  NULL or blank typically means it's a database level permission.
    - ObjectName - the name of the object in question.  NULL or blank typically means it's a database level permission.
    - ObjectType - the type of the object in question.
    - PermissionScope - the scope of the permission (DATABASE, OBJECT_OR_COLUMN, etc.)
    - Permission_Type - the type of the permission.
    - Permission_TypeName - the type of the permission (in english).
    - Permission_State - the state of the permission (GRANT, DENY, etc.)

    #OwnedSchemas
    - ServerName - the name of the server.
    - DatabaseName - the name of the database.
    - SchemaName - the name of the schema.
    - OwnerName - the name of the owner.
    - OwnerSID - the owner's SID
    - OwnerType - the owner user type.
    - OwnerTypeDesc - the owner's type description.
    - ObjectCount - the number of objects that belong to the schema. 

More Information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx

********************/

--Table to hold User Permissions
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UserPermissions') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #UserPermissions 
END

CREATE TABLE #UserPermissions
    (
    ServerName SYSNAME NULL
    , DatabaseName SYSNAME NULL
    , [SID] VARBINARY(85) NULL
    , ServerUserName SYSNAME NULL
    , DatabaseUserName SYSNAME NULL
    , RoleName SYSNAME NULL
    , RoleOwnerName SYSNAME NULL
    , UserType CHAR(1) NULL
    , UserTypeDesc VARCHAR(50) NULL
    , DefaultSchema SYSNAME NULL
    , DateCreated DATETIME2 NULL
    , RoleGrantedThrough SYSNAME NULL
    , SchemaName SYSNAME NULL
    , ObjectName SYSNAME NULL
    , ObjectType VARCHAR(200) NULL
    , PermissionScope VARCHAR(200) NULL
    , PermissionType VARCHAR(10) NULL
    , PermissionTypeName VARCHAR(200) NULL
    , PermissionState VARCHAR(100) NULL
    )

--Table to hold Schema Information...
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OwnedSchemas') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #OwnedSchemas 
END

CREATE TABLE #OwnedSchemas
    (
    ServerName SYSNAME NULL
    , DatabaseName SYSNAME NULL
    , SchemaName SYSNAME NULL
    , OwnerName SYSNAME NULL
    , OwnerSID VARBINARY(85) NULL
    , OwnerType CHAR(1) NULL
    , OwnerTypeDesc VARCHAR(50) NULL
    , ObjectCount INT NULL
    )

--Server Level Permissions...
;WITH ServerRoles (member_principal_id, role_principal_id, GrantedThrough)
AS
(
SELECT rm1.member_principal_id
    , rm1.role_principal_id
    , NULL AS GrantedThrough
FROM sys.server_role_members rm1 (NOLOCK)
UNION ALL
SELECT P.principal_id
    , NULL
    , NULL
FROM sys.server_principals P (NOLOCK)
UNION ALL
SELECT d.member_principal_id
    , rm.role_principal_id
    , d.role_principal_id AS GrantedThrough
FROM sys.server_role_members rm (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN ServerRoles d ON d.role_principal_id = rm.member_principal_id 
)
--Use distinct to get rid of things like public repeating for each user...
INSERT INTO #UserPermissions
SELECT DISTINCT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
    , NULL AS DatabaseName
    , UseRolePrincipalrincipal.[sid]
    , UseRolePrincipalrincipal.name AS ServerUserName
    , NULL AS DatabaseUserName
    , RolePrincipal.name AS RoleName
    , RoleOwner.name AS RoleOwnerName
    , UseRolePrincipalrincipal.[type] AS UserType
    , UseRolePrincipalrincipal.type_desc AS UserTypeDesc
    , NULL AS DefaultSchema
    , UseRolePrincipalrincipal.create_date
    , GrantedViaPrincipal.name AS RoleGrantedThrough
    , NULL AS SchemaName
    , NULL AS ObjectName
    , NULL AS ObjectType
    , DBPerm.class_desc AS Permission_Scope
    , DBPerm.[type] AS Permission_Type
    , DBPerm.[permission_name] AS Permission_TypeName
    , DBPerm.state_desc AS Permission_State
FROM ServerRoles drm
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals RolePrincipal ON RolePrincipal.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals UseRolePrincipalrincipal ON UseRolePrincipalrincipal.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals RoleOwner ON RoleOwner.principal_id = RolePrincipal.owning_principal_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals GrantedViaPrincipal on GrantedViaPrincipal.principal_id = drm.GrantedThrough 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_permissions DBPerm ON DBPerm.grantee_principal_id = CASE WHEN drm.role_principal_id IS NULL THEN drm.member_principal_id ELSE drm.role_principal_id END

DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE curDB CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY
FOR SELECT D.name
    FROM sys.sysdatabases D
    ORDER BY D.name 

OPEN curDB

FETCH NEXT FROM curDB
INTO @DatabaseName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    --Get the User Permission Information.
    SET @Query = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
        + ' ;WITH RoleMembers (member_principal_id, role_principal_id, GrantedThrough )
            AS
            (
            SELECT rm1.member_principal_id
                , rm1.role_principal_id
                , NULL AS GrantedThrough 
            FROM sys.database_role_members rm1 (NOLOCK)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT P.principal_id
                , NULL
                , NULL AS GrantedThrough
            FROM sys.database_principals P
            UNION ALL
            SELECT d.member_principal_id
                , rm.role_principal_id
                , d.role_principal_id AS GrantedThrough
            FROM sys.database_role_members rm (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN RoleMembers d ON d.role_principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
            ) 
            --Use distinct to get rid of things like public repeating for each user...
            INSERT INTO #UserPermissions
            SELECT DISTINCT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
                , DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
                , UserPrincipal.[sid]
                , ServerPrincipal.name AS ServerUserName
                , UserPrincipal.name AS DatabaseUserName
                , RolePrincipal.name AS RoleName
                , RoleOwner.name AS RoleOwnerName
                , UserPrincipal.[type] AS UserType
                , UserPrincipal.type_desc AS UserTypeDesc
                , UserPrincipal.default_schema_name AS DefaultSchema
                , UserPrincipal.create_date
                , GrantedViaPrincipal.name AS RoleGrantedThrough
                , S.name AS SchemaName
                , O.name AS ObjectName
                , O.type_desc AS ObjectType
                , DBPerm.class_desc AS Permission_Scope
                , DBPerm.[type] AS Permission_Type
                , DBPerm.[permission_name] AS Permission_TypeName
                , DBPerm.state_desc AS Permission_State
            FROM RoleMembers drm
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals RolePrincipal ON RolePrincipal.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals UserPrincipal ON UserPrincipal.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals GrantedViaPrincipal on GrantedViaPrincipal.principal_id = drm.GrantedThrough 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals RoleOwner ON RoleOwner.principal_id = RolePrincipal.owning_principal_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_permissions DBPerm ON DBPerm.grantee_principal_id = CASE WHEN drm.role_principal_id IS NULL THEN drm.member_principal_id ELSE drm.role_principal_id END
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects O ON O.[object_id] = DBPerm.major_id AND DBPerm.class = 1
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas S ON (S.[schema_id] = O.[schema_id] AND DBPerm.class = 1) OR (DBPerm.class = 3 AND S.[schema_id] = DBPerm.major_id)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals ServerPrincipal ON ServerPrincipal.[SID] = UserPrincipal.[SID]'

        EXEC sp_executesql @Query 

        --Get the Schema Information...
        SET @Query = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
            + ' INSERT INTO #OwnedSchemas
                SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
                , DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
                , S.name AS SchemaName
                , P.name AS OwnerName
                , P.[SID]
                , P.[type] AS OwnerType
                , P.type_desc AS OwnerTypeDesc
                , COUNT(O.object_id) AS ObjectCount
            FROM sys.schemas S
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects O ON O.schema_id = S.schema_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals P ON P.principal_id = S.principal_id
            GROUP BY S.name
                , P.name 
                , P.[SID]
                , P.[type]
                , P.type_desc'

        EXEC sp_executesql @Query 

        --Loop to the next database.
        FETCH NEXT FROM curDB
        INTO @DatabaseName

END

CLOSE curDB
DEALLOCATE curDB

SELECT * FROM #UserPermissions

SELECT * FROM #OwnedSchemas

/*** Some Useful Queries


--Distinct Permission Types.
SELECT DISTINCT PermissionType, PermissionTypeName
FROM #UserPermissions
ORDER BY PermissionType


--High Privilege Accounts...
--ALTER objects, Impersonate, Control, Create Tables, Reference Objects, Take Ownership or can GRANT to others.
--or members of db_owner, ddladmin , securityadmin, sysadmin on either database or server levels. 
SELECT * 
FROM #UserPermissions
WHERE PermissionType IN ('IM', 'AL', 'CL', 'CRTB', 'RF', 'TO')
    OR PermissionState = 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'
    OR RoleName IN ('db_owner', 'db_ddladmin', 'db_securityadmin', 'sysadmin', 'securityadmin', 'serveradmin')

**/


/*** Generate Fix Scripts.

    The fix scripts below will generate various fix scripts for certain conditions.  
        I.E. - fix users who can grant permissions.


******************************************************************************************************************
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
******************************************************************************************************************

--Fix Schemas owned by orphaned users.
--If the schema has objects, change the owner to dbo.  
--If the schema does not have objects, drop the schema.
;WITH OwnedSchemaFix
AS
(
SELECT OS.*
    , P.name AS ServerUserName
FROM #OwnedSchemas OS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals P ON P.[sid] = OS.OwnerSID
WHERE OwnerType = 'U'
    AND P.name IS NULL      
)
SELECT ServerName   
    , DatabaseName
    , SchemaName
    , OwnerName
    , OwnerType
    , FixStatement = CASE   WHEN ObjectCount = 0
                                THEN 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) + '; DROP SCHEMA ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName)
                            WHEN ObjectCount <> 0
                                THEN 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) + '; ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA:: ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + ' TO [dbo]'
                            END
FROM OwnedSchemaFix 

******************************************************************************************************************
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
******************************************************************************************************************

--Fix Orphaned Users
--Change owner of schema or drop schema (if no objects).
--Drop the user.
;WITH OrphanedUserFix
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT U.ServerName
                , U.DatabaseName
                , U.DatabaseUserName
                , U.ServerUserName
                , U.[SID] 
FROM #UserPermissions U
WHERE U.DatabaseName IS NOT NULL --Only want database level accounts.
    AND U.ServerUserName IS NULL --No entry in sys.server_principals.
    AND U.UserType <> 'R' --Ignore roles.
    AND [SID] <> 0x00 --Ignore system generated users.
)
SELECT E.*
FROM    (
        --Drop Schemas First.
        SELECT F.ServerName
            , F.DatabaseName
            , F.DatabaseUserName
            , F.ServerUserName
            , FixStatement = CASE WHEN S.ObjectCount <> 0 THEN 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(F.DatabaseName) + '; ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA:: ' + QUOTENAME(S.SchemaName) + ' TO [dbo];'
                                    ELSE 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) + '; DROP SCHEMA ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName)
            , FixStatementInt = 1
        FROM OrphanedUserFix F
            INNER JOIN #OwnedSchemas S ON S.OwnerSID = F.[SID]
        UNION ALL
        --Drop Users Second.
        SELECT F.ServerName
            , F.DatabaseName
            , F.DatabaseUserName
            , F.ServerUserName
            , FixStatement = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(F.DatabaseName) + '; DROP USER ' + QUOTENAME(F.DatabaseUserName)
            , FixStatementInt = 2
        FROM OrphanedUserFix F 
        ) E
ORDER BY E.DatabaseName, E.DatabaseUserName, E.FixStatementInt, E.FixStatement

******************************************************************************************************************
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
******************************************************************************************************************

--Generate script to fix GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION
--This will revoke all rights for principals to subsequently pass their permissions onto others.  

;WITH GrantFix
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM #UserPermissions
WHERE PermissionState = 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'
    AND RoleName IS NULL
)
SELECT DatabaseName 
    , ServerUserName
    , DatabaseUserName
    , SchemaName
    , ObjectName
    , PermissionType 
    , PermissionTypeName
    , PermissionState 
    , FixStatements = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) + '; REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ' + PermissionTypeName + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + CASE WHEN ObjectName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ('.' + QUOTENAME(ObjectName)) END + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseUserName) + ' CASCADE AS [dbo];'
FROM GrantFix
WHERE DatabaseName IS NOT NULL  
ORDER BY DatabaseName, ServerUserName, DatabaseUserName, SchemaName, ObjectName, PermissionTypeName

******************************************************************************************************************
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
******************************************************************************************************************

--Generate script to remove all permissions to use REFERENCE.
--REFERENCE allows users to create objects that have FK references to other tables.
;WITH ReferenceFix
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM #UserPermissions
WHERE PermissionType = 'RF'
    AND PermissionState = 'GRANT'
    AND RoleName IS NULL
)
SELECT DatabaseName 
    , ServerUserName
    , DatabaseUserName
    , SchemaName
    , ObjectName
    , PermissionType 
    , PermissionState 
    , FixStatements = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) + '; REVOKE ' + PermissionTypeName + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + CASE WHEN ObjectName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ('.' + QUOTENAME(ObjectName)) END + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseUserName) + ' CASCADE AS [dbo];'
FROM ReferenceFix
WHERE DatabaseName IS NOT NULL



******************************************************************************************************************
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
******************************************************************************************************************


****/
```